# WordPress plugin development theme issue

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-shortcode

Developed the WordPress plugin using https://materializecss.com/ framework , Once plugin activated it will automatically create 4 pages in WordPress. Here I'm facing one issue with WordPress multiple theme. In some of the theme they are directly writing CSS for the elements without using any classes or id. For example: `body{ margin:0; padding:0;} button{width:40px}` Like this they have done because of this its affecting all the pages created by plugin. For temporary solution override those styles from plugin itself. But its differ based on themes can't able to override each and every CSS properties.

*Anyone know how to solve this issue please post your answer here. Because of this issue still plugin not pushed to WordPress.Org market place.*

Comment: Can you share your plugin via GitHub, Google Drive & other platforms.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is related to my organization. Its not my own plugin so I can't share the plugin. If you can't understand my question let me know I will explain you clearly. Thanks :)

Comment: It's too difficult to identify your problem without inspecting your code.

Comment: Let me clearly explain you I have one button tag with unique class name eg: six-storage-cc is my class name. I have given styles for that like button.six-storage-cc{ margin: 0px; }I didn't given any color or padding but in some WordPress theme they are giving without using any classes directly giving styles for button tag example: button{ padding:12px; border-radius:10px}. Like this only facing the issue for many theme. Thanks in Advance!